# AntBuilder unzip encoding

Tags: groovy

I am unzipping a file under Windows in a Groovy script like this:

```groovy
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.unzip(  src: path.absolutePath,
            dest: directoryName,
            overwrite: "false")
```

The zip file contains files with German Umlauts in their name (like "Glück"), these file names are damaged after the unzipping. It is clear that I run into an encoding issue here. So I tried to set the encoding:

```groovy
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.unzip(  src: path.absolutePath,
            dest: directoryName,
            overwrite: "false",
            encoding: "XXX")
```

But whatever encoding I tried (from this [site](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/unzip.html)), I was not able to solve my issue:

- `"windows-1252"` or `"cp1252"` lead to an java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException
- `"ISO-8859-1"` just removed the special chars
- `"Utf-8"`, `"native-encoding"` or no encoding lead to wrong characters

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `"Cp850"` and everything worked. However I had to find the correct code page with try-and-error. I would have expected that UTF-8 will work or that `"native-encoding"´ would find the right encoding as every zip tool does.